# Suspect traffic from 185.0.0.0/8

Tags: networking, iptables, network-traffic

I have a server/gateway running Debian 7. There is a big incoming traffic (for a homemade server) from an ip address located at 185.0.0.0/8 network for more than 40k packets in 24h. I have blocked all the incoming traffic from this cidr, but they keep trying to connect. I've been looking for over a month for this. Searching [whois](http://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/185.0.0.1) for this ip address gave me vague info.
What is this network? Who is the owner?

Comment: 40k in 24 hours? That's *nothing*. TomTom's phone could handle that without breaking a sweat.

Comment: Yes, but beeing a home server, with almost nothing on it, having very low traffic, that is much.

Comment: Do you have a specific IP address? That netblock you named is much too large to determine anything.

Comment: I don't have the ip address, as this happened over a month ago, and my old log is 1 month old.

Answer (score 3):

If you're concerned about the traffic, collect logs, and send them off to the abuse contact listed in the whois record for the specific IP you're concerned about.

Honestly, though, don't bother. Things like this are just part of the internet background noise. Unless you can **prove** they are malicious or are causing performance problems, it's not worth your time.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to look up who is running an entire /8 net-block.

In this case and most others it isn't a single organization that controls the block, but the regional organization that handles the allocation (in this case RIPE for Europe) has split the block up and distributed it as smaller CIDR blocks. <s>In order to find out who to contact for abuse you will need to look-up the individual IPs to see who has the allocations.</s> 
It looks like that this hasn't been updated in WHOIS yet or it is perhaps a legacy allocation. Either way EEAA's suggestion about not worrying about it is most likely your best bet.

Also, except for some legacy allocations no one actually owns IP addresses. The are assigned by five regional organizations around the world. If you are not using them effectively or using them for *bad things* than they can be revoked.

Comment: I know about the organizations that distribute the IPs, but looking up a specific ip from this cidr gave me nothing. That's just suspect.

Comment: `185.0.0.0/8` is the last `/8` in the RIPE region. This `/8` is subject to rationing, nobody can get more than one `/22` from this block. There is no legacy in this block.